# C# problems with configure cors

Tags: c#, cors

I have been trying for several hours over the last few days to fix my cors problems. My JS is running in the brower to call my currently locally running endpoint.
I am having Cors problems and I have tried several things to get on with my local development.
I have read in some articles and Stackoverflow post that chrome can not handling cors ob localhost so I have also tried this.

open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir

But it did not work. Also with other browsers.

Here is my C# Code.

```
using Amazon;
using Amazon.DynamoDBv2;
using Customers.Api.Contracts.Responses;
using Customers.Api.Repositories;
using Customers.Api.Services;
using Customers.Api.Validation;
using FastEndpoints;
using FastEndpoints.Swagger;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var config = builder.Configuration;
var  MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("127.0.0.1:5000","127.0.0.1:5001", "http://127.0.0.1:5000","http://localhost:5000"
                "http://127.0.0.1:5001").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

builder.Services.AddAWSLambdaHosting(LambdaEventSource.HttpApi);
builder.Services.AddFastEndpoints();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerDoc();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAmazonDynamoDB>(_ => new AmazonDynamoDBClient(RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICustomerRepository>(provider =>
    new CustomerRepository(provider.GetRequiredService<IAmazonDynamoDB>(),
        config.GetValue<string>("Database:TableName")));
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
app.UseMiddleware<ValidationExceptionMiddleware>();
app.UseFastEndpoints(x =>
{
    x.ErrorResponseBuilder = (failures, _) =>
    {
        return new ValidationFailureResponse
        {
            Errors = failures.Select(y => y.ErrorMessage).ToList()
        };
    };
});
app.UseOpenApi();
app.UseSwaggerUi3(s => s.ConfigureDefaults());
app.Run();
```

and this is my Javascript code

```
var payload = {
              event: eventData,
              signupType: signupType,
              name: name,
              email: email,
              birthdate: birthdate,
              gender: gender,
              orientation: orientation,
              partner: {
                name: partnerName,
                email: partnerEmail,
                birthdate: partnerBirthdate,
                gender: partnerGender,
                orientation: partnerOrientation,
              }
            };
          
            
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/customers', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
              },
              body: JSON.stringify(payload)
            })
            .then(function(response) {
              if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
              }
              return response.json();
            })
            .then(function(data) {
              console.log('Success:', data);
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
              console.error('Error:', error);
            });
          });
```

This are my error messages...
[image: error messages]

I haven't any idea what I can try now. And I think about to rewrite this piece in node.js and express because there I haven't normally problems with configure the cors rules...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error from your browser it looks like the origin is 'null'. So, what I would suggest you try is adding the string "null" to the list of origins when you add the .WithOrigins parameter.

The problem is that you've added the IP/Ports of the request destination in there (your .NET App) and not the origin of the request which in your case is not being found and is being set to null.

Can I ask what the address is of the site you're calling your Javascript from? Also, does it work when you add the string "*" to the list of origins? Keep in mind you don't want this in a production level environment setting.

Comment: First try "null" was working. But the browser was still in the mode without security futures.  So the combination works. I have tried without the future and I get again cors problems. I have also tried a local dev server with hosting the page on localhost:80 and added localhost:80 and 127.0.0.1 and "*" and it don't worked on all of my browsers. Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Can you try the following please.

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});

Just replace everything in the list with the "*" and then try with the local dev server. What we're doing here is allowing any kind of access to the application via CORS. You can then work backwards from there to see where the issue is.

Comment: builder.WithOrigins("").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
still get this message =>
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/customers' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: the WithOrigins("") you posted is wrong its actually WithOrigins("*"). Also, apologies, I typed it out wrong the first time

Comment: I have thought that you mean "*" I have tried both. But I got the same message.

Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/customers' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.